# "No emulator images (avds) found" mesmo depois de criar imagens de emulador

Tags: apache-cordova

Tenho o seguinte problema:

```
Error: No emulator images (avds) found.
1. Download desired System Image by running: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4/tools/android sdk
2. Create an AVD by running: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4/tools/android avd
HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver
```

Já criei duas imagens de emulador pelo comando `android avd`

Comment: Qual a saída do comando `which android`? Outra coisa, você já baixou (`android sdk`) as imagens que quer emular?

Comment: @zekk já consegui emular. O problema agora é o tamanho da tela do emulator. Fica uma dimensão baixa e tudo expremido. Como alterar isso? E como acelerar o emulador, que é tão lento?

Comment: Veja aqui o ponto 3 a ver se ajuda: http://www.markupjavascript.com/2015/03/most-common-phonegap-errors-with-solutions.html

Answer (score 0):

para ficar mais rapido ai mesmo fala

```
 HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver
```

pela msg vc deve estar usando Windows, se seu CPU for compativel [instale o HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) e ao criar o AVD use imagem X86 (Nao use X86_64) , no meu laptop , com Linux e usando KVM (o HAXM pra Linux) meu AVD roda em 9 segundos .

ja sobre a tela , tente fazer um AVD usando API23 , ainda tenho problemas de Rendering com a API24 tambem.